# ADFS redirects to login screen when calling site via http web request

Tags: claims-based-auth, credentials, redirect

I have configured Sharepoint with ADFS (claims-based auth). There is another web site (probably on a different machine) that shall be shown in a web part - just like page viewer it is hosted in an iframe. The url to that web part can be configured by the web part. To be able to do that, the other web site is contacted from the Sharepoint server via c# code.

Unluckily as the response of my httpwebrequest I get the login screen of ADFS back. When switching autoredirect to false, one can see the try to redirect to log in screen.

The problem here seems to be that the credentials will not be delivered to the web site via the web request as the call is done on server side not from browser (where it will probably work).

Is there any possibility to make that working?
- probably by sending the used cookies to the server?
- delegating the user information to the adfs login page?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are trying to send a "claim" to a non-claims application (your remote web site).

If SharePoint and your other webapp are in the same domain, You may be able to utilize the claims to windows token service (ADFS 2) or the ADFS agent (ADFS 1.1) to consume the claim on the external webapp.  Admittedly I have no experience implementing this.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee517278.aspx

Otherwise you will probably need to send these credentials manually in code or utilize the secure store service.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554863.aspx

Comment: No, both applications are claims-enabled. ADFS seems to support only 
1. Call from browser to server (passive)
2. Call from server side (Sharepoint) to any other server only via WCF configured as WS-Trust. (active)
Calling another claims based application from the Sharepoint server seems to be not accomplish-able with HttpWebRequest without reinventing the whole stuff. Is it really a mixture of both active and passive?

Comment: Wish I could provide further insight, but unfortunately, that's going a bit beyond my scope of knowledge. If you have not, you may want to check out the MSDN page here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/aa570351 which is the launch pad for the identity management.  I would also post in the identity/ADFS forums http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Geneva/threads/

Comment: I'll have a look onto that. Thanks for your help anyway :-)